# How to serialize/deserialize Object

Tags: c#, mongodb, windows-phone-8, bson, mlab

I'm writting a Wp8/C# library for querying REST Api of MongoLab.
I have an `abtract` object like this :

```
[DataContract]
public abstract class Entity
{
    [DataMember(Name = "_id")]
    public string _id { get; set; }
}
```

The field `_id` is autogenerate by Mongo as a ObjectId. But with WP8, I don't have the mongoDb C# driver... The serialization and deserialization doesn't work....

This is what I've tried :

```
var str = url;
var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(str);
var rep = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(rep);
```

I've tried with Datacontractjsonserializer too.

How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: You do not need to put tag information in the title, that is what tags are for.

Comment: What have you tried - you say the serialization etc does not work - can you share the code that does not work?

Comment: You cannot serialize/deserialize abstract classes.

Comment: Even if my class is not abstract, the serialization or deserialization failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a class I wrote for dealing with JSON serialization and deserialization in .NET 3.5
Don't forget to add a reference to System.ServiceModel.Web.dll

You can use JsonTools.ObjectToJsonString(rep);

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
using System.IO;

namespace Utilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Group of static methods for dealing with JSON.
    /// </summary>
    public static class JsonTools
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes an object to JSON string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The object to serialize. </param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <exception cref="System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.ServiceModel.QuotaExceededExceptionn"></exception>        
        public static string ObjectToJsonString(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                MemoryStream jsonStream = new MemoryStream();
                DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
                js.WriteObject(jsonStream, obj);
                jsonStream.Position = 0;

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(jsonStream);
                return sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Serializes an object to JSON byte array.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The object to serialize. </param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        /// <exception cref="System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException"></exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.ServiceModel.QuotaExceededExceptionn"></exception>  
        public static byte[] ObjectToJsonByteArray(object obj)
        {
            try
            {
                MemoryStream jsonStream = new MemoryStream();
                DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
                js.WriteObject(jsonStream, obj);
                jsonStream.Position = 0;

                return jsonStream.ToArray();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes a JSON formatted string to an object of the defined type
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="jsonString">JSON formatted string</param>
        /// <param name="objType">The type of the object which the jsonString is to be Deserialized to.</param>
        /// <returns>Deserialized object</returns>
        /// <exception cref="System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException"></exception>
        public static object JsonStringToObject(string jsonString, Type objType)
        {
            try
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(objType);
                byte[] jsonBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(jsonString);
                MemoryStream jsonStream = new MemoryStream(jsonBytes);

                return js.ReadObject(jsonStream);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Deserializes a JSON formatted byte array to an object of the defined type
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="jsonBytes">JSON formatted byte array</param>
        /// <param name="objType">The type of the object which the jsonString is to be Deserialized to.</param>
        /// <returns>Deserialized object</returns>
        /// <exception cref="System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException"></exception>
        public static object JsonByteArrayToObject(byte[] jsonBytes, Type objType)
        {
            try
            {
                DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(objType);
                MemoryStream jsonStream = new MemoryStream(jsonBytes);

                return js.ReadObject(jsonStream);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: It's working but my _id is a Dictionnary[string, object] and it doesn't work with this class...

Comment: I don't think you can do it with a generic type of Object